# Перенос букв в div и вертикальное центрирование

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать вертикальное центрирование текста в этом `<div>` и как перенести буквы которые не поместились в блоке на новую строку?

```html
<div style='width: 75px;height: 75px;border: 2px solid #777; padding: 10px;border-radius: 5px;font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
 font-size:16px;background:#4e27d3;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;'>Формирование задачи</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для переноса добавьте `word-break: break-all;`, а для центровки `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

```css
.block {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 2px solid #777;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #4e27d3;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    Формирование задачи
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Для переноса букв на следующую строку используйте "word-wrap: break-word;" в style
[Описание атрибута](http://htmlbook.ru/css/word-wrap)

Проблему с высотой можно исправить с помощью атрибута line-height и подобрать значение для него
Пример использования, в том числе и для div найдете [здесь](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2014/04/line-height-css.html)

Comment: Конкретно для данного примера `line-height` не отцентрирует текст в пределах блока, а просто будет увеличивать растояние между строк, что позволит только растянуть на весь блок.